# How to update an existing table with a new column from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two db tables involved.

```
**table 1:**

coupon_name || coupon_amount || coupon_id || coupon_status

**table 2:** 

coupon_id || coupon_name || store_name
```

I want to add the coupon_amount column on table 2. How do I do that in mysql?

Comment: If you need to add a column to the table then use ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN query.

Comment: Do you really need to , you could join the tables to get the amount per store based on coupon_id.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  What you want as a result set is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Table 2 doesn't have the column "coupon_amount", so first you have to add that to the table.
The next step would be to add the records from table 1 to the target table.
You can use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table2'
ADD COLUMN 'coupon_amount' INT (or the type of the field you have in table 1);
```

Then, you need to execute the second step, that can be like this query:

```
UPDATE 'table2'
INNER JOIN 'table1' ON 'table2'.'coupon_id' = 'table1'.'coupon_id'
SET 'table2'.'coupon_amount' = 'table1'.'coupon_amount';
```